# react-native-device-info get getUniqueID() not working with react native and expo in android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to get device info & get referral code for referring and earn program for a mobile app with **React Native & Expo**.

Check my step
1. Install npm by using

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info
```

2. Linking with

```
react-native link react-native-device-info
```

3. Using

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

const deviceName = DeviceInfo.getUniqueID();
```

I am getting an error of

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNDeviceInfo.uniqueId')

Answer (score 1):

use `getUniqueId` instead of `getUniqueID`

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

const deviceName = DeviceInfo.getUniqueId();
```